# Heightmap generation finishes halfway through

Tags: opengl, perlin-noise

Currently, I'm trying to make a noise generated heightmap and display it with opengl. I'm following [this tutorial](https://lwjglgamedev.gitbooks.io/3d-game-development-with-lwjgl/content/chapter14/chapter14.html), but my heightmap doesn't seem to work. It seems like it generates (or displays) only half of what it is supposed to.

This is the heightmap with normals for color:
[image: Heightmap]

As you can see, even though this is supposed to be a square, it appears rectangular with an unfinished edge.

This is my heightmap generation code:

```
public class HeightMap extends GameModel {

    private static final float START_X = -0.5f;
    private static final float START_Z = -0.5f;

    public HeightMap(float minY, float maxY, float persistence, int width, int height) {
        super(createMesh(minY, maxY, persistence, width, height));
    }

    protected static Mesh createMesh(final float minY, final float maxY, final float persistence, final int width,
            final int height) {
        SimplexNoise noise = new SimplexNoise(128, persistence, 2);// Utils.getRandom().nextInt());

        float xStep = Math.abs(START_X * 2) / width;
        float zStep = Math.abs(START_Z * 2) / height;

        List<Float> positions = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < height; z++) {
                // scale from [-0.5, 0.5] to [minY, maxY]
                float heightY = (float) ((noise.getNoise(x, z) + 0.5f) * (maxY - minY) + minY);

                positions.add(START_X + x * xStep);
                positions.add(heightY);
                positions.add(START_Z + z * zStep);

                // Create indices
                if (x < width - 1 && z < height - 1) {
                    int leftTop = z * width + x;
                    int leftBottom = (z + 1) * width + x;
                    int rightBottom = (z + 1) * width + x + 1;
                    int rightTop = z * width + x + 1;

                    indices.add(leftTop);
                    indices.add(leftBottom);
                    indices.add(rightTop);

                    indices.add(rightTop);
                    indices.add(leftBottom);
                    indices.add(rightBottom);
                }
            }
        }

        float[] verticesArr = Utils.listToArray(positions);
        float[] colorArr = new float[positions.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < colorArr.length; i += 3) {
            colorArr[i] = (float) i / colorArr.length;
            colorArr[i + 1] = (float) .25f;
            colorArr[i + 2] = (float) 0;
        }
        int[] indicesArr = indices.stream().mapToInt((i) -> i).toArray();

        float[] normalArr = calcNormals(verticesArr, width, height);

        return new Mesh(verticesArr, colorArr, normalArr, indicesArr);
    }

    private static float[] calcNormals(float[] posArr, int width, int height) {
        Vector3f v0 = new Vector3f();
        Vector3f v1 = new Vector3f();
        Vector3f v2 = new Vector3f();
        Vector3f v3 = new Vector3f();
        Vector3f v4 = new Vector3f();
        Vector3f v12 = new Vector3f();
        Vector3f v23 = new Vector3f();
        Vector3f v34 = new Vector3f();
        Vector3f v41 = new Vector3f();
        List<Float> normals = new ArrayList<>();
        Vector3f normal = new Vector3f();
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
                if (row > 0 && row < height - 1 && col > 0 && col < width - 1) {
                    int i0 = row * width * 3 + col * 3;
                    v0.x = posArr[i0];
                    v0.y = posArr[i0 + 1];
                    v0.z = posArr[i0 + 2];

                    int i1 = row * width * 3 + (col - 1) * 3;
                    v1.x = posArr[i1];
                    v1.y = posArr[i1 + 1];
                    v1.z = posArr[i1 + 2];
                    v1 = v1.sub(v0);

                    int i2 = (row + 1) * width * 3 + col * 3;
                    v2.x = posArr[i2];
                    v2.y = posArr[i2 + 1];
                    v2.z = posArr[i2 + 2];
                    v2 = v2.sub(v0);

                    int i3 = (row) * width * 3 + (col + 1) * 3;
                    v3.x = posArr[i3];
                    v3.y = posArr[i3 + 1];
                    v3.z = posArr[i3 + 2];
                    v3 = v3.sub(v0);

                    int i4 = (row - 1) * width * 3 + col * 3;
                    v4.x = posArr[i4];
                    v4.y = posArr[i4 + 1];
                    v4.z = posArr[i4 + 2];
                    v4 = v4.sub(v0);

                    v1.cross(v2, v12);
                    v12.normalize();

                    v2.cross(v3, v23);
                    v23.normalize();

                    v3.cross(v4, v34);
                    v34.normalize();

                    v4.cross(v1, v41);
                    v41.normalize();

                    normal = v12.add(v23).add(v34).add(v41);
                    normal.normalize();
                } else {
                    normal.x = 0;
                    normal.y = 1;
                    normal.z = 0;
                }
                normal.normalize();
                normals.add(normal.x);
                normals.add(normal.y);
                normals.add(normal.z);
            }
        }
        return Utils.listToArray(normals);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild guess: You're using 16bit indices but specify the size of the index buffer as if it were 8bit indices (by setting the size of the buffer to number of elements in the buffer)?

Judging from the screenshot, it clearly looks like only the first half is drawn, so I would assume the problem lies in the creation of the index buffer or the draw call.

Maybe you used the wrong number of indices in the draw call? Like you used the number of triangles instead? Or assumes the number for a triangle fan instead of triangles?

You'll have to post the actual draw call and generation of the buffer objects to get more information.

Or at least tag your question according to the rendering library you are using, as it is not plain OpenGL.

Comment: I was using vertices.length instead of indices.length for the drawing call. Thanks!